# How to allow filtering by only date parts selected by user and make not selected work as "Any"?

Tags: views, datetime

I am using the Date module and I am creating a view to display news content; I made a exposed filter to search news content by year, month, and day. When I search, I need to select all the date fields.

Is it possible to search entering values for just one of those fields?

How can I remove these validation in search time?

[image]

How can I remove this validation from exposed search filters ?
I want to search content 
condition should like this:-
**Year "OR" Month "OR" Day**

condition should not like this:-
**Year "AND" Month "AND" Day**

Comment: Hello and welcome. Removing validation will not affect mechanism of search, it would just allow you to give it information it cannot process, input that would make it throw PHP or database errors, so I'm pretty sure that's not exactly what you really want. Could you explain what do you think by "Year" wise and so on? I mean, you are in this project for a pretty some time but try to read your question as if you weren't - it's not that obvious when you do that, right? We may guess, and probably guess right, but clear answer will bring you more clear and fitting answers :)

Comment: Now the body of a question is pretty clear. At least if what you want is to be able, for example, to select December posts from all years. Title has nothing to do with it, sadly. Please consider changing title to match actual need, and not your idea of solution, to avoid closure. Note: The fact it's clear now sadly does not mean I know the solution :(

Answer (score 1):

It **validated**, because by default it set to **AND operator** in your exposed setting. You can do it easily, but I have done it in Drupal 6, I don't have D7 setup. Check the below screenshots. Just select the **Method as OR** in the exposed filter setting.

[image]

Click the **setting icon** and then select the **OR** under method.

[image]